# Conditional formatting only affects Values

Tags: matrix, powerbi, format

How come my power BI only can change the conditional formatting of values but not my columns or rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is currently no workaround to apply a conditional formating to a full row or columns.

You can request features on [PowerBI Ideas website](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/). If your suggestion is upvoted enough, it may or may not be featured in a future release.